# inserting and reversing elements in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem of using an insert method and reverse method that i am trying to make within a constructor as i am new and this is an exercise example. For the inserting constructor i have:
It is supposed to insert an element at index in the array

```
public boolean insert(int index, int element)
{
    int i;
    newArray = new int[Array.length + 1];
    for(i = index; i > newArray.length - 1; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = newArray[i + 1];

        for(i = 0; i < newArray.length + 1; i++)
        {
            Array[i] = newArray[i];
        }
    }
    Array[index] = element;
    numElement = numElement + 1;
    return true;
```

and my reverse constructor is:

```
public boolean reverse(int start, int end)
{
    int temp;
    for(int i = start; i <(start + end) / 2 ; i++)
    {
        temp = Array[i];
        Array[i] = Array[end - i];
        Array[end - i] = temp;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

when i use the insert constructor it would replace the number and not make a new array to accomodate the extra element and before the output closes it would give me an exception error. For the reverse, it would not give me the correct output. Eg: i have an array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` and i want to reverse numbers 3-7 it would output `[1,2,6,5,4,3,7,8,9,10]`. I don't know what could be wrong with the code.
EDIT: Also i am trying not to use any Arrays.util methods/ArrayList and such

Comment: You keep using the word _constructor_. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: The insert method is very confusing to me.  `newArray[i] = newArray[i + 1];` would appear to do nothing since newArray is declared just before.  I assume perhaps there is a typo in this line?

Comment: what i tried to do was make a new array that is one size larger, then copy the contents of the original array into the new one, allowing it to add one more element

Answer (score 2):

There is a Java reverse method for arrays:

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(int[] array) //Reverses the order of the given array.
```

And also for add:

```
ArrayUtils.add(int[] array, int element) //Copies the given array and adds the given element at the end of the new array.
```

Answer (score 0):

If not using ArrayUtils (why not?), then perhaps use `System.arraycopy` for the insert method.

Also, these are not constructors, they are methods.  They probably should also be void methods or return the new array and not a boolean (unless there is a reason to return a boolean here?).

Example insert method using System.arraycopy:

```
public static int[] insert(int[] list, int position, int value)
{
    int[] result = new int[list.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(list,0,result,0,position);
    result[position] = value;
    System.arraycopy(list,position,result,position + 1,list.length - position);
    return result;
}
```